# display.newText isnt working

Tags: text, lua, coronasdk

first time user of Stackoverflow;

Problem: even at the basic level of trying to print out simply Hello world nothing seems to happen.

using this:

```
local text = display.newText("helloworld", 50, 50, native.systemFont, 24)
print(text)
```

the varible "text" when printed holds the value of "Table: 010F3E50" which changes on each reload

im new to this language and this is really annoying - Any help would be fantastic

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you are trying to print the object. Not the text inside. So try:

```
print(text.text)
```

Instead of:

```
print(text)
```

Keep coding............ :)

Comment: great, thanks that worked to print the text inside onto the console, but im still having trouble displaying this text onto my simulator.

any thoughts?

thanks again

Comment: Glad I could help. What is the issue you are facing now?

Answer (score 0):

The color of the text might be black by default which might be the same color as the background in the simulator.  Meaning it's visible but you just can't see it!

Trying changing the color of the text object by doing this:

```
text:setFillColor(1,0,0) -- red text
```